# How to match url by domain name in href attribute?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

How to match url by domain name in the href attribute? I currently have two regexes but they don't work in `grep` or `ag`. They do however work in Sublime Text. Also is this possible without lookahead/lookbehind?

Data:

```
<a href="/url?q="http://somedomain.com/file.txt">
```

Regex:

```
(?<=url\?q=\").*(somedomain\.com)[^"]*
(url\?q=\s*"\K)[^"]*(pastebin\.com)[^"]*
```

Answer (score 0):

It works with `grep` if you use perl-compatible regexps (`-P`). But you do not need any perl-specific patterns:

```
 grep '/url[?]q="[^"]*somedomain'
```